# Query needs "allowLargeResults". "Error: Unexpected" when it is added

Tags: google-bigquery

When running a largish query with several levels of subqueries and joins, I get

```
Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults 
to true in your job configuration.
```

However, when adding allowLargeResults, I instead get

```
Unexpected. Please try again.
```

I've tried tweaking the query from what I can find of solutions others have posted to similar errors here, but to no avail. I've also tried running the query from both the command line and web interfaces (`sincere-woods-825:bqjob_r3c3aa54d659ea8a3_0000014c6b3e36bc_1` and `sincere-woods-825:job_IOVaOjnA1H4Q-FzBdGGGLQh7uMc` are my latest attempts from the command line and web interface respectively).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query references measurement-lab tables, and `allowLargeResults` queries are not supported right now on those -- they're a special kind of table hosted by BigQuery for certain projects at Google.

We should improve the error message, but `allowLargeResults` queries over these tables are unlikely to be supported. Instead, we'd like to migrate them to "native" BigQuery tables.  If you can contact the owner of these tables, let them know that it would be helpful for your ability to run queries that generate large outputs to have these migrated to normal BigQuery tables.

Also note that the original error message suggesting `allowLargeResults` appeared because the output generated by your query was too large, not because of SQL complexity.  If you can pare down number of rows returned, or the overall size of the query output, you might be able to make it succeed without using `allowLargeResults`.

Comment: Aha, excellent, thanks! I'll try to split up the results to have them fit. Is there a number somewhere for how big query results can be before allowLargeResults is needed?

Comment: The limit is [128MB compressed](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries).

Comment: Right, that gives a ballpark, at least. Thanks again! :)